# Possible to use different log4j appenders for different methods?

Tags: java, log4j

I have a log4j configuration file and it uses a ConsoleAppender with a specific layout.

I use 
    logger.info("some text"); 
in several places in my java code.

Is it possible to create another appender with a different layout in the configuration file and use the specific appender wherever I choose in the code?

Comment: What are you using for log4j configuration. `XML` or `properties`?

Comment: I am using XML. Already have a <appender><layout></layout></appender>.

Comment: OK I have to update my post.

Comment: OK I have updated my post. Hopefully it will work.

Answer (score 2):

> Is it possible to create another appender with a different layout in the configuration file and use the specific appender wherever I choose in the code?

Yes you can create different appender with a different layout and create different categories for each appender.

**use the category name to get the logger instead of appender name.**

---

**Sample: (`log4j.xml`)**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<!DOCTYPE log4j:configuration SYSTEM "log4j.dtd">

<log4j:configuration xmlns:log4j="http://jakarta.apache.org/log4j/">

    <appender name="stdout1" class="org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender">
        <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
            <param name="ConversionPattern" value="[%.4t] %-5p %c{1} - %m%n" />
        </layout>
    </appender>

    <appender name="stdout2" class="org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender">
        <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
            <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%d [%.4t] %-5p %c{1} - %m%n" />
        </layout>
    </appender>

    <category name="category1">
        <priority value="INFO" />
        <appender-ref ref="stdout1" />
    </category>

    <category name="category2">
        <priority value="DEBUG" />
        <appender-ref ref="stdout2" />
    </category>

</log4j:configuration>
```

Java Code: (**get the logger based on category name**)

```
org.apache.log4j.Logger.getLogger("category1").warn("debug msg for stdout1 appender");
org.apache.log4j.Logger.getLogger("category2").info("info msg for stdout2 appender");
```

Output:

```
[main] WARN  category1 - warn msg for stdout1 appender
2014-05-09 02:46:29,216 [main] INFO  category2 - info msg for stdout2 appender
```

Comment: Can you really retrieve a logger by its appender name (i.e. `Logger.getLogger("stdout1")`)?

Comment: Don't always trust the output. Try the following: `Logger.getLogger("stdout3")`. It will also work, even though there are no *stdout3* appender defined. My guess is that your example works because it falls through to the root logger. log4j will get a requested `stdout1` (or `stdout3`) logger, won't find it, fall back to the root logger. 

It works for your simple example, but try to define those appenders on a different logger, remove them from the root logger (leaving one default appender but that clearly identifies the root logger), and you'll see it breaks. I've tested it and confirm this.

Comment: I added the additional appender and removed the %d from the new appender. getLogger seems to print out the name of the logger but I still get the date printed out.

Comment: @jlr I think that's the purpose of root logger. If no appender found then falls to root logger. Isn't it?

Comment: Yes that's right, but you cannot retrieve a logger with an **appender name** via the `Logger.getLogger(String name)` method. The appenders are used in your example because they are defined on the root logger and this one will always get used. But move the appenders away from the root logger and the `Logger.getLogger("stdout1")` call is useless. Your solution is almost there but misses the definition of two extra loggers that each define one appender.

Comment: @jlr I have deleted the root logger that was creating the confusion here.

Comment: Finally I have corrected it. **Get the Logger by its category name instead of appender name**. Thanks a lot @jlr

Comment: Thanks @Braj, it's better as it should work, but using a Logger instead of Category would be better. Because a Category is technically the same as a logger and is deprecated (it was supposed to be removed in mid 2003, to tell you how deprecated it is :) ), please refer to this link: http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/apidocs/org/apache/log4j/Category.html

Comment: @jlr Please can you post it as an answer to make it clear to me as well as for others.

Comment: But as per document - **// Deprecated form:** `Category cat = Category.getInstance("foo.bar")` and **// Preferred form for retrieving loggers:** `Logger logger = Logger.getLogger("foo.bar")`. I am using second one that is preferred.

Comment: Yes, maybe it's fine in configuration to use a category. Your answer is good so if I would offer mine, I'd just copy yours but replace the categories in the config by loggers! Thanks for correcting your answer!

Comment: @jlr I think there is no issue of using logger in configuration file. JavaDoc is talking about the `Category.getInstance()` as deprecated form. If you found any reference about the configuration then please share. Thanks a lot again.